# Does an external .js file require <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, script-tag, external-js

Does an external .js file require internal and containing  tags to work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, they're not needed, in fact you'll get a syntax error if you include them.

Your `.js` files should contain *only* JavaScript, no HTML tags around it, like would have inside a page.

Comment: It looks fairly ugly when I take my embedded JS to external.  How should one organize the little snippets?  For example, I have one for pressing search or cancel, then another to sign out, etc which I have in separate `<script>` tags in a `.php` file but when I move these to a `.js` file the only way I have to organize them now is with a comment line dividing them.  That just does not seem right.

Answer (score 8):

No, it does not.  The external file just needs the code.
Then you just need to do `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: I would add a stronger warning here, not only are tags not needed, they'll actually FUBAR things :)

Comment: type attribute is not required but optional since html5

Answer (score 2):

External Javascript should not contain  tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, `<script>` tags are not needed otherwise error occurs.

For example, `external.js` has `alert` function with `<script>` tags.

##### external.js:

```html
<script>
  alert('external')
</script>
```

Then, `external.js` is added to `index.html`.

##### index.html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

Then, error occurs. (I used `google chrome`)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

So, only `alert` function is fine without `<script>` tags.

##### external.js:

```js
alert('external')
```