# Does jQuery have to be written in the <script> tags in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jQuery, and I'm running into a small problem. jQuery code works when I put it directly in my  tags in my HTML, but when I import it from a different file, nothing happens. These are my script tags in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/test.js"></script> <!--This is my jQuery code-->
```

`test.js` contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("Hello");
});
```

When the page loads, the console is empty. However, when I paste the following code as so, in my html document, everything works fine.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: It should work, problem must be somewhere else. Is path an filename correct?

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in dev tools?

Comment: There must be a path declaration problem , otherwise it should be works

Comment: Do you see something like "cannot find file" in errors?. Add jQuery from an online CDN. It might help you to check if this is a path problem.

Comment: No as per this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859966/does-an-external-js-file-require-script-tags

Comment: I actually don't see anything at all in my console. It's just blank when I refresh my page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have a folder named *scripts* in the folder where your HTML files exist? Otherwise try changing this `src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"` to probably this: `src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"`

You can check by browsing to `http://yoururl/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js`, the Jquery code should show up. If it's not there, you have to make sure that you include the right folder/file.

Comment: Adding the preceding forwardslash caused a `cannot find resource` error in Chrome. Also, I did what you said by typing in the URL to the file, and the text shows up fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You will be able to push your scripts in 2 ways::
1-push your scripts in  tag like>>

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){alert("Welcome Dear");});</script>
```

2-push your inline scripts with attributes like>>

```
<button type='button' onclick="$(this).hide()">Hide Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the scripts folder contain test.js make sure that the extension is correct ..sometimes I make the same same mistake, instead of test.js i save it as test.js.txt

Comment: Triple-checked the file names and path, everything seems to be in order.

Comment: code works perfect in my system..please change the code as $(document).ready(function(){
alert("Hello");
}); so that you can see it in browser

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

in the body rather than the head.

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106462/whats-the-difference-between-putting-script-in-head-and-body) answer for giving the idea